# Cant run any docker image after system upgrade

Tags: docker

I've upgraded a OS today (from xubuntu 19 to xubuntu 20 in case its useful) and my docker images stopped working. Docker command itself work, but when I try to run any image (like postgres for example), I always get

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
```

at the end (of course various images have different entrypoints but none of them can start, always for similar reason).

I ran docker system prune -a --volumes, reinstalled docker with snap (snap uninstall docker && snap install docker). Docker run still doesn't work, it pulls the image but at the end I get the same error.

I'm running out of ideas how to approach it. What can be an issue?

// edit

Exact command I run:

```
$ docker run postgres
Unable to find image 'postgres:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/postgres
afb6ec6fdc1c: Pull complete 
51be5f829bfb: Pull complete 
e707c08f571a: Pull complete 
98ddd8bce9b5: Pull complete 
5f16647362a3: Pull complete 
5d56cdf9ab3b: Pull complete 
2207a50ca41d: Pull complete 
a51d14a628f3: Pull complete 
24dcb11335d0: Pull complete 
54cc759cb0bb: Pull complete 
debc11d66570: Pull complete 
3ffd0589b5fc: Pull complete 
490b7ee49751: Pull complete 
3511c6be34a0: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ec7cfff29672a2f676c11cc53ae7dafe63a57ccefc2b06ea423493227da29b9c
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:latest
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you print the command you run and the result please ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA added to question

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/636#issuecomment-633180897. If fact, I've found that in general docker from apt is more stable than docker from snap

Comment: @SiHa I did it already and yeah it fixed the issue but would be good to know for the future what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

what permissions does the file /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
have? try to print them and see if you have permission to edit them in the currennt user.

I can see a solution that worked in here - https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Permission-Denied-quot-exec-entrypoint-sh-quot/td-p/31249