# Al docker images exit 126 status

Tags: docker

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.0 and installed docker using snap. I'm trying to run some different docker images for `hbase` and `rabbitmq` but each time I start an image, it immediately exists with `126` status.

```
$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS               NAMES
4d58720fce3a        dajobe/hbase        "/opt/hbase-server"   5 seconds ago        Exited (126) 4 seconds ago                            hbase-docker
b7a84731a05b        harisekhon/hbase    "/entrypoint.sh"      About a minute ago   Exited (126) 59 seconds ago                           optimistic_goldwasser
294b95ef081a        harisekhon/hbase    "/entrypoint.sh"      About a minute ago   Exited (126) About a minute ago                       goofy_tu
```

I have tried everything and tried to use `docker inspect` on separate images, but nothing gives away, why the containers exit out immediately. Any suggestions?

### EDIT

When i run the command i run the following

```
$ sudo bash start-hbase.sh
```

It gives the output exactly like it should

```
Starting HBase container
Container has ID 3c3e36e1e0fbc59aa0783a4c7f3cb8690781b2d04e8f842749d629a9c25e0604
Updating /etc/hosts to make hbase-docker point to  (hbase-docker)
Now connect to hbase at localhost on the standard ports
  ZK 2181, Thrift 9090, Master 16000, Region 16020
Or connect to host hbase-docker (in the container) on the same ports

For docker status:
$ id=3c3e36e1e0fbc59aa0783a4c7f3cb8690781b2d04e8f842749d629a9c25e0604
$ docker inspect $id
```

I think the issue might be due to some permissions, because i tried to chck the logs as suggested in the comments, and get this error:

`/bin/bash: /opt/hbase-server: Permission denied`

Comment: you could try to check the logs: `docker logs <ID>`.

Comment: @clemens It gives me permission deined... I can't see the logs

Comment: Can you add the complete `docker run` command you use and for the `docker log`, you should prefix it with sudo like you do for the docker ps command you paste.

Comment: The 126 return code is when the container could not execute the contained command (like the entrypoint or the cmd): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/exit-status

Comment: I have updated the question with new description.

Comment: There have been [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62019005/10008173) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61990562/10008173) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61967505/10008173) around bizarre "permission denied" errors using Docker from Snap.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62022953/10008173) isn't specifically Ubuntu, but has a pretty detailed diagnosis.

Comment: This was really weird. I originally installed via snap from the ubuntu software store. I then uninstalled and reinstalled using regular wget , and apt install.
It worked fine...

Answer (score 2):

Check if the filesystem is mounted with `noexec` option using `mount` command or in /etc/fstab. If yes, remove it and remount the filesystem (or reboot).

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is **restart service docker** and **network-manager**

Comment: Did this but the error persist